# ¿Cómo se podría aplicar el concepto de inclusividad en español?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

El otro día aprendí el concepto de [inclusividad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusividad) aplicado al lenguaje:

> La **inclusividad** o **clusividad** es una distinción del sistema pronominal de las lenguas del mundo por el cual la primera persona del plural posee una forma inclusiva y otra forma exclusiva, respecto al oyente. Es decir, la primera persona plural inclusiva tiene una forma de pronombre que significa "yo + tú + (posiblemente otros)" y la forma de primera persona plural exclusiva significaría "yo + otro(s), pero no tú".

El idioma español carece de este concepto, el cual aprendí en [un vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYlVJlmjLEc) (en inglés) que aplicaba el siguiente ejemplo:

> ¡Hemos ganado la lotería!

¿Cómo sabe la persona a la que se dirige la frase si él está incluido en la misma? ¿Cuál sería la forma más adecuada de añadir este concepto de inclusividad al español? Quiero decir, ¿cuál es la mejor forma de expresar en español "nosotros incluido tú" y "nosotros excluido tú"? Se admiten respuestas incluso aunque no correspondan al español actual, en caso de que en épocas antiguas existiera algún recurso para expresar este concepto que se haya perdido hoy.

Comment: Interestingly the English version of that article dates the first mention to a Spanish writer in 1560 so if it ever existed in Spanish it must pre-date that or have been invented and lost again after that.

Comment: @mdewey the mention to a Spanish writer refers to a work of american languages like Quechua or Aymara

Comment: @blonfu yes, I know, but if the concept had existed before that in Spanish presumably his work would not have counted as the first mention as he would have said that Quechua or Aymara is like Spanish in this respect.

Comment: @mdewey I'm not sure if I understand correctly, my English is limited. The concept of clusivity exist in Spanish language too but not a different word to differentiate them

Comment: @blonfu yes, I agree we are confusing one another. Shall we leave it to Carlos to make use of our comments if he wishes?

Comment: @mdewey sorry for the confusion. My question is about how to best express in Spanish the concept of "inclusive we" and "exclusive we". The question is not limited to the nowadays Spanish, so answers regarding the Spanish from centuries ago are welcome. Question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curiosamente hace tiempo encontré [una pregunta acerca de este concepto en Inglés](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14438/is-there-any-language-that-uses-different-pronouns-for-we-depending-on-whether), donde se explicaba que en vietnamita se utilizan [pronombres particulares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_pronouns) para excluir (*chúng tôi*, *chúng tao*) e incluir (*chúng ta*, *mình*, *chúng mình*) al interlocutor.

Esa pregunta me hizo reflexionar acerca del concepto y cómo utilizarlo en Español de una manera muy similar aquí. A continuación compartiré algunas de mis conclusiones.

Primeramente, fui incapaz de encontrar si existía un pronombre "*prehistórico*", a mí parecer, tales pronombres por lo menos deberían estar en el Quijote de Cervantes. Sin embargo, debo decir que no tuve suerte en un lugar de la Mancha de cuyo pronombre no pude encontrar.

Ingeniosos hidalgos aparte, consideraría que si tales pronombres no están en la obra que consolidó la lengua Española su existencia sería más allá de dudosa.

Por lo que si se ha de encontrar cómo aplicar el concepto de clusividad es necesario buscar otras alternativas para lograrlo. Siendo que el Español lleva siglos en uso, es probable que hayan mecanismos para expresar este concepto. El primero que pensé es el uso de lenguaje corporal mencionado por [Nox](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/13956/nox), pero ese recurso va más allá del Español en sí, dado que se puede aplicar a cualquier lenguaje.

Posteriormente, recordé frases en las que se excluían a los interlocutores. Bajo esta perspectiva, "nosotros" siempre sería inclusivo (incluyendo al interlocutor) hasta que se realizará la aclaración explícita de que se le excluye.

He aquí ejemplos de tal implementación:

- Nosotros, menos tú, vamos a salir. *(Excluyendo al interlocutor)*
- Nosotros, excluyéndote, vamos a salir. *(Excluyendo al interlocutor)*
- Nosotros, excluyendo la presente compañía, vamos a salir. *(Excluyendo al interlocutor)*
- Nosotros vamos a salir sin ti. *(Excluyendo al interlocutor)*
- Ellos/Ellas/*Grupo* y yo vamos a salir.
- Nuestra familia va a salir.
- Nosotros, los adultos, vamos a salir. *(Excluyendo a los interlocutores menores)*

Lo más notable de estos ejemplos es el uso de dos herramientas "linguísticas":

- El uso de un pronombre que no incluye al interlocutor más la inclusión explícita de la primera persona.
- El uso de una unidad grupal que claramente excluye al interlocutor.

El caso de la unidad grupal que excluya al interlocutor es el más ambiguo, ya que requiere conocimiento de la persona a la que uno se refiere. Esto es más difícil lograrlo al escribir por lo que un recurso literario sería el escribir en tercera persona, evitando una narración en primer persona.

Así bien, se pueden aplicar inversamente para indicar la inclusión explícita del interlocutor en caso de desar implementar el concepto de inclusión:

- Ustedes/tú y yo vamos a salir.

A final de cuentas, espero que los ejemplos anteriores sirvan para recordarnos frases de nuestra niñez en las personas mayores tenían que ingeniárselas para expresar la inclusión y exclusión de un grupo. A mí el ejercicio me recordó familiares y maestros con frases semejantes a las presentadas anteriormente.

Answer (score 4):

Excluyendo el contexto lingüístico y el lenguaje corporal, una forma posible de marcar exclusividad sería un recurso que veo habitualmente en mi dialecto (rioplatense) y que es usar *acá* como deíctico de manera figurativa (sea que además se refiera a un lugar físico o no):

- **Acá** nosotros podemos arreglarnos bien así. No sé ustedes.
- Los regalos que trajo el jefe son para nosotros **acá**, no para repartir entre todas las oficinas.
- **Acá** tu madre y yo vamos a salir; vos tenés que quedarte estudiando.

Answer (score 1):

Responderé solo algunas preguntas, pues me resulta interesante pero tampoco tengo los conocimientos para responderlas todas, por ejemplo si alguna vez existió una forma concreta de expresar este concepto en español.

- **¿Cómo sabe la persona a la que se dirige la frase si él está incluido en la misma?**
  **¿cuál es la mejor forma de expresar en español "nosotros incluido tú" y "nosotros excluido tú"?**

Contexto y lenguaje corporal (que no por que en este medio solo escribamos, deba desaparecer o debamos obviarlo). Principalmente contexto diría yo, tampoco es algo tan difícil de expresar o averiguar:

> -¡Hombre, si es Pablo! ¿Cómo te va?
>   -¿Qué tal, Manuel? ¡A mí genial! El otro día compramos un boleto de la lotería de navidad, ¡y hemos ganado un pastón!

No incluye al interlocutor.

> -Oye, ¿has mirado el boleto que compramos el otro día?
>   -Déjame ver... ¡Hostia! ¡Que hemos ganado la lotería!

Incluye al interlocutor.

Obviamente he elegido contextos relativamente fáciles, pero sinceramente, tampoco se me ocurren muchas ocasiones en que fuera mucho más difícil deducirlo, y aún así, siempre está el lenguaje corporal (amén de especificar per sé que el interlocutor no está incluido):

> -¡Nosotros! - Dijo mi padre meneando su mano de un lado a otro, señalando al resto de mi familia - Vamos a salir. Tú no vas a ningún lado, que estás castigado.
>   Y así, con un dedo acusador aireando mi nariz, murieron mis esperanzas de salir a dar una vuelta.

- **¿Cuál sería la forma más adecuada de añadir este concepto de inclusividad al español?**

Si te refieres a una palabra concreta solo para expresar ese concepto, no creo que sea necesario, pero tampoco es que haya muchas posibilidades, habría que "inventarse" una palabra nueva. A bote pronto no se me ocurre nada, la verdad.
Si te refieres a expresarlo con lo que tenemos ahora mismo, pues eso, contexto y lenguaje corporal.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la respuesta! Se ve que una de las preguntas no quedó clara, y siento una vez más los malentendidos. Con la pregunta que abordas al final de tu respuesta simplemente quería decir lo mismo que con la aclaración posterior: que cómo podemos expresar los conceptos de "nosotros inclusivo" y "nosotros exclusivo". Es decir, lo que tratas en todo el resto de tu respuesta. Y sobre lo de no abordar el español antiguo, no era necesario, no te preocupes.